# Selecting minimum value between columns python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like the below. "Name" represents a student name and values below each of the Test variables represent the test grade.

```
Name Test1 Test2 Test3
Ana  87    93    82
Cole 62    73    84
Sia  64    58    60
Max  93    95    99
Leah 93    90    85
Cam  76    80    83
```

The desired result is the DataFrame below. Where "MinTestGrade" represents that lowest grade each student earned between the 3. "TestNumber" is the Test they got the lowest grade on.

```
Name TestNumber MinTestGrade
Ana  3          82
Cole 1          62
Sia  2          58
Max  1          93
Leah 3          85
Cam  1          76
```

How can I do this using python?

Comment: As a database design aside, your original dataframe is NOT a good database design.  (It's not "3rd Normal Form".).  Your master database should look like the second example, with a column for "test number" and a column for "test grade".  Then, your query becomes trivial.

Comment: Very true. I’m aware the database design isn’t practical. However this is the database I have to work with unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `idxmin` and `min` to `agg` on axis to find the minimum grade and the column name, i.e. TestNumber, that it corresponds to for each student. Then `join` the outcome with "Name", rename the columns and finally strip the word "Test" from "TestNumber":

```
out = df[['Name']].join(df.filter(like='Test').agg(['idxmin', 'min'], axis=1)).rename(columns={'idxmin':'TestNumber', 'min':'MinTestGrade'})
out['TestNumber'] = out['TestNumber'].str.lstrip('Test').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   Name  TestNumber MinTestGrade
0   Ana           3           82
1  Cole           1           62
2   Sia           2           58
3   Max           1           93
4  Leah           3           85
5   Cam           1           76
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.set_index("Name").agg(["idxmin", "min"], axis=1).reset_index()
#    Name idxmin  min
# 0   Ana  Test3   82
# 1  Cole  Test1   62
# 2   Sia  Test2   58
# 3   Max  Test1   93
# 4  Leah  Test3   85
# 5   Cam  Test1   76
```